# Does C++17 std::basic_string_view invalidates the use of C strings?

Tags: c++, c, c++17

C++17 is introducing `std::basic_string_view` which is non-owning string version with its class storing only a pointer to the first element of a string and size of the string. Is there still a reason to keep using C strings?

Comment: Was there **ever** a reason to keep using C strings in C++? (Not trying to be a smarta.. here, I am genuinely unsure what you're asking.)

Comment: For storage, (when `std::string` is not required) ?

Comment: @Amani do you mean to ask if one should now always write `string_view myStr("someCstring");` instead of const `char* myStr = "someCstring";`, even if the string will later be used to pass to e.g. 3rd party functions taking const char*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there still a reason to keep using C strings?

I think it would be fair to say that other than speaking to a C API, there has *never* been a reason to use C strings.

When designing an interface of a function or method that simply needs a read-only representation of characters, you will want to prefer `std::string_view`. E.g. searching a string, producing an upper-case copy, printing it, and so on.

When designing an interface that takes a copy of a string of characters, you should probably prefer first and last iterators. However, `std::string_view` could be thought of as a proxy for these iterators, so `string_view` is appropriate.

If you want to take ownership of a long string, probably prefer to pass `std::string`, either by value or by r-value reference.

When designing an object that marshals calls to a c API that is expecting null-terminated strings, you should prefer std::string or std::string const& - because its c_str() method will correctly yield a null-terminated string.

When storing strings in objects (which are not temporary proxies), prefer std::string.

Of course the use of `const char*` as an owner of data in c++ is never appropriate. There is always a better way. This has been true since c++98.

Comment: "I think it would be fair to say that other than speaking to a C API, there has never been a reason to use C strings." Because std::string needs typically a dynamic allocated memory to store the content, it is not very common on small embedded systems to use std::string for static strings which can be kept in flash space without a copy.

Comment: @Klaus fair. I have a template class `immutable_string` for such use cases.

Answer (score 6):

"Invalidate" has a technical meaning here which I think is unintentional.  It sounds like "obviate" is the intended word.

You are still going to have to produce and consume C strings in order to interact with common APIs.  For example, POSIX has `open` and `execve`, Win32 has the rough equivalents `CreateFile` and `CreateProcess`, and all of these functions operate on C strings.  But in the end, you are still calling `str.data()` or `str.c_str()` in order to interact with these APIs, so that use of C strings is not going away, no matter whether `str` is a `std::basic_string_view` or `std::basic_string`.

You will still have to understand what C strings are in order to correctly use these APIs.  While `std::string` guarantees a NUL terminator, `std::string_view` does not, and neither structure guarantees that there is no NUL byte somewhere inside the string.  You will have to sanitize NUL bytes in the middle of your string in either case.

This does not even touch on the wealth of 3rd party libraries which use C strings, or the cost of retrofitting your own code which uses C strings to one which uses `std::string_view`.

Comment: ...either of which is easily supplied by `.data()`...?

Comment: @DevSolar: …which returns a C string?

Comment: ...which still means you hold the string data in a C++ object that'll properly resize and destruct, instead of doing manual memory management.

Comment: `even if str can now either be std::basic_string or std::basic_string_view.`

A `string_view` is not guaranteed to be NULL-terminated. Using it directly with a C-style API is likely to produce unintended results. You have to copy it into a std::string, and then do a `.c_str()`

Comment: @DevSolar: I think you are interpreting the question differently than the way I am.  I interpreted passing `str.data()` to an API as "using C strings", and you appear to consider that insufficient.  However, your claim that `std::basic_string_view` will properly resize and destruct is incorrect… the basic string view is equally subject to dangling pointers as a `char *` is.

Comment: @sbabbi: Yes, I think that goes without saying.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Yep, just pointing out, as some readers might be not too familiar with `string_view`.

Comment: The point I was argueing was more along the lines of "Is there (now that we have `string_view`) a reason to still use C strings?" -- "(Exceptional cases like the one pointed out by @AdrianMaire nonwithstanding) there was no reason to still use C strings *before* we had `string_view`". Argueing in favor of `std::string` instead of either `char[]` or `string_view`. Just with not as many words, but apparently the lightheartedness got lost in translation. ;-)